# JavaFX search in listview

Tags: java, listview, search, javafx-8

I want to search in listview and my code is working but not well enough. The problem is when i write few characters in the search text field not only the result appears, but the rest of the items also appear...

The code:

```
// Wrap the ObservableList in a FilteredList (initially display all data).
    FilteredList<Client> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(main.getClientListData(),p -> true);

    //Set the filter Predicate whenever the filter changes.
    searchUserTF.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        filteredData.setPredicate(client ->{
            // If filter text is empty, display all persons.
            if(newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()){
                return true;
            }

            // Compare first name and last name of every client with filter text.
            String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();

            if(client.getFirstname().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)){
                return true; //filter matches first name
            }else if(client.getLastname().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)){
                return true; //filter matches last name
            }
            return false; //Does not match
        });
    });

    //Wrap the FilteredList in a SortedList.
    SortedList<Client> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);

    //put the sorted list into the listview
    clientListView.setItems(sortedData);
```

Photos:
Original list:
[image: Original list]

Sorted list:
[image: Sorted list]

ListCell implementation:

```
 clientListView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Client>, ListCell<Client>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<Client> call(ListView<Client> param) {
            final Label leadLbl = new Label();
            final Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
            final ListCell<Client> cell = new ListCell<Client>(){
              @Override
                public void updateItem(Client item, boolean empty){
                  super.updateItem(item,empty);
                  if(item != null){
                      leadLbl.setText(item.getFirstname());
                      setText(item.getFirstname()+" "+item.getLastname());
                      tooltip.setText(item.getFirstname());
                      setTooltip(tooltip);
                  }
              }
            };
            return cell;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is not in your filter logic.

I think you have a bad `ListCell` implementation that does not clear its text when it is supposed to display nothing.

**Update**

Yeah, your cell renderer does not clear the cell when the item is `null`.  Try something like this:

```
        final ListCell<Client> cell = new ListCell<Client>(){
          @Override
            public void updateItem(Client item, boolean empty){
              super.updateItem(item,empty);
              if(item != null){
                  leadLbl.setText(item.getFirstname());
                  setText(item.getFirstname()+" "+item.getLastname());
                  tooltip.setText(item.getFirstname());
                  setTooltip(tooltip);
              }
              else {
                  leadLbl.setText("");
                  setText("");
              }
          }
        };
```

Comment: You probably also want `setTooltip(null)` in the `else` clause (otherwise hovering over empty cells might give strange results).